# Can't scale two edge loops around the X axis

Tags: edges

I have these 2 edge loops and I want to scale them to be further apart, but using <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and dragging the mouse won't move (along the Y and Z axis it works). I can set them apart manually by taking each one and moving it using G but I want them to be equally apart.

[image]

Here is a 'perspective' view of the shape, maybe I did something wrong that prevents me from scaling those loops.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have 'Individual Origins' set as your pivot point for transformations in the 3D view header toolbar. At the minute each loop is scaling towards it's *individual* origin but because the loops have no thickness themselves nothing appears to be happening.

You need 'Median Point' set:

[image]

This will find the point in between the two edgeloops in 3d space and use that as the origin for transformations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed it! I'm still a beginner at 3D modelling and blender :D

Comment: If this answer has helped you then please mark it as 'accepted'. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers