# Scaling Question On Blender 2.79b

Tags: modeling

I just started learning Blender yesterday and I'm stuck in scaling. I was trying to recreate a tutorial by Blender Guru creating this coffee mug but early part i cannot do what he is doing.

While trying to scale the bottom of the cup, mine will constrain but Blender Guru's on scale sideways and do not constrain.

I'm finding it hard to expalin here so I put together a side-by-side video of my attempt and the original tutorial.

In this video, LEFT SIDE is my attemp and the RIGHT SIDE is Blender Guru
https://youtu.be/ATWzqG_Kf_k

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33553/change-pivot-point-for-selected-edges and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15150/cant-scale-two-edge-loops-around-the-x-axis/ Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92606/how-to-rotate-all-objects-along-their-local-z/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Duarte posted in the comments it seems that your pivot point is off.In the video you posted it seems that your pivot point is set to 3D Cursor.

You can set your pivot point in the view port menu. In the tutorial you are doing the pivot point is set to `Median Point`.

[image]

Comment: Hello there, you solved my problem. I didn't know how it got there but YES, thank you sir :)

Comment: If his answer helped you Zamboolah, please select it and give him some points, it will display your question as answered to other users as well.